# Selenium Webdriver finding an element (a button)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need my script to click on a button.  So far I have tried this-

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("button_click")).click();
```

and HTML for this button is-

```
    <td class="Button">
<input class="btn" value="Click here to get started" name="button_click" onclick="this.form.action = '/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=0076878676545487SVD2&eid=465124652J9ly&ic=1&retURL=%24848676854684y&wrapMassAction=1&scontrolCaching=1&linkToken=gituuiyiiuhjgd46etfjgioyyo8yo8ylihvTDNfLWhzdm5KLFlXWmtNR0po'; this.form.onsubmit = function() { return true }" title="page title" type="submit"/>
</td>
```

but it is not identifying the button right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to search for your button by `id`, but your button has no `id`. The solution is to add an `id` to the button with the corresponding value:

```
    <td class="Button">
<input class="btn" value="Click here to get started" id="button_click" name="button_click" onclick="this.form.action = '/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=0076878676545487SVD2&eid=465124652J9ly&ic=1&retURL=%24848676854684y&wrapMassAction=1&scontrolCaching=1&linkToken=gituuiyiiuhjgd46etfjgioyyo8yo8ylihvTDNfLWhzdm5KLFlXWmtNR0po'; this.form.onsubmit = function() { return true }" title="page title" type="submit"/>
</td>
```

If this is not an option, then you can search for elements by `name`, but then a list will be returned and you will need to choose the correct element from there, which is pretty simple if there is a single element.

Comment: Thank you. I just spaced out that name thing

Comment: With pleasure, happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
driver.findElement(By.Name("button_click")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("input.btn:nth-of-type(X)")).click();
```

there is probably more than one input with 'btn' class in your page, so X would represent wich one of these buttons you want.